# Datatables Date Range Filter using Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, jquery-ui-datepicker

I cannot get table filtered by date range selected using Datepicker. I was unable to find any solutions that work in my case.

My HTML:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" 
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" data-server="2.0.3" data-require="jquery"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="1.9.4" data-require="datatables@*" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" data-server="1.9.4" data-require="datatables@*" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/css/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" data-server="1.9.4" data-require="datatables@*" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" data-server="1.9.4" data-require="datatables@*" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/css/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" data-server="1.9.4" data-require="datatables@*" />
    <link data-require="jqueryui@*" data-server="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jqueryui@*" data-server="1.10.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js" data-server="1.9.4" data-require="datatables@*"></script>
    <div class="input-daterange">
    <input type="text" id="min" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" id="max" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <table class="user-table" id="datatable"> 
    <thead>
         <th>ID</a></th> 
         <th>Date</th> 
         <th>Receipt #</th> 
         <th>Mbr #</th> 
         <th>First Name</th> 
         <th>Last Name</th> 
         <th>Description</th> 
         <th>Transaction Type</th> 
         <th>(-/+) Amount</th> 
         <th>Expense Type</th> 
         <th>Income type</th> 
         <th>Balance</th> 
         <th>Added By</th> 
         <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ....
    </tbody>
```

My JavaScript:

```
    // The plugin function for adding a new filtering routine
            $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex){
                var dateStart = parseDateValue($("#min").val());
                var dateEnd = parseDateValue($("#max").val());
                // aData represents the table structure as an array of columns, so the script accesses the date value 
                // in the second column of the table via aData[1]
                var evalDate= parseDateValue(aData[1]);

                if (evalDate >= dateStart && evalDate <= dateEnd) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }

            });

            $(document).ready(function(){           
                var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({

                });

                $('#min,#max').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImageOnly: "true",
                    buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
                    weekStart: 1,
                    changeMonth: "true",
                    changeYear: "true",
                    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0",
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true
                });

                // Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs
                $('#min,#max').change(function(){ oTable.fnDraw(); });
            });
```

[view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naKcs.jpg)

Comment: Try wrapping the plugin code within `$(document).ready`. see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/w4gmr87v/10/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately that didn't work. Instead, I lost my datepicker and datatable formatting, and even when inputting the dates manually it still didn't filter.

Comment: To those, who might be interested, there's the same subject discussed with bunch of solutions over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691908/datatablesdatepicker-filter-table-by-date-range