# DataTables+Datepicker filter table by date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, datepicker

Trying to implement DataTables filter by date range using two bounded datepickers.

I've seen few similar questions at SO, but none of those having answers worked for me.

So far, I managed to implement interface elements, but have no idea as of how to put them together to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

```js
var myTableData = 
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "$86,000",
      "start_date": "2009/01/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1562"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$433,060",
      "start_date": "2012/03/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6224"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Airi Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$162,700",
      "start_date": "2008/11/28",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "5407"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "Brielle Williamson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$372,000",
      "start_date": "2012/12/02",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4804"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Herrod Chandler",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$137,500",
      "start_date": "2012/08/06",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "9608"
    }
];

$('.datepicker').datepicker();

var myDataTable = $('#staff').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: myTableData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'Name', data: 'name'},
    {title: 'Position', data: 'position'},
    {title: 'Office', data: 'office'},
    {title: 'Hire date', data: 'start_date'},
    {title: 'Salary', data: 'salary'}
  ]
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Start date:</label>
    <input id="startdate" class="datepicker"></input>
    <label>End date:</label>
    <input id="enddate" class="datepicker"></input>
    <button id="filter">Filter</button>
    <table id="staff"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (slightly modified) example with certain added value (timezone independent, limited year range, bounded datepickers):

```js
//Data definition
var myTableData =
  [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Garrett Winters",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$170,750",
    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "8422"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Ashton Cox",
    "position": "Junior Technical Author",
    "salary": "$86,000",
    "start_date": "2009/01/12",
    "office": "San Francisco",
    "extn": "1562"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2012/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Airi Satou",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$162,700",
    "start_date": "2008/11/28",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "5407"
  }, {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Brielle Williamson",
    "position": "Integration Specialist",
    "salary": "$372,000",
    "start_date": "2012/12/02",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4804"
  }, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "Herrod Chandler",
    "position": "Sales Assistant",
    "salary": "$137,500",
    "start_date": "2012/08/06",
    "office": "San Francisco",
    "extn": "9608"
  }
];
//Global variable for future use
var datepickers = [{
    id: 'startdate',
    coid: 'enddate',
    value: null,
    limiter: 'minDate'
  }, {
    id: 'enddate',
    coid: 'startdate',
    value: null,
    limiter: 'maxDate'
  }
];
//Translate 'yy/mm/dd' string to UTC date
const yymmddUTC = str => new Date(...str.split('/').map((value,index) => index == 1 ? value-- : value));
//DataTables object definition
var myDataTable = $('#staff').DataTable({
    sDom: 't',
    data: myTableData,
    columns: [{
        title: 'Name',
        data: 'name'
      }, {
        title: 'Position',
        data: 'position'
      }, {
        title: 'Office',
        data: 'office'
      }, {
        title: 'Hire date',
        data: 'start_date'
      }, {
        title: 'Salary',
        data: 'salary'
      }
    ]
  });
//Limit datepicker options to those valid for current dataset
var dates = myDataTable.column(3).data().unique().sort();
var minDate = dates[0];
var maxDate = dates[dates.length-1];
//datepicker objects definition
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
  changeMonth: true,
  defaultDate: minDate,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: minDate.substr(0,4)+':'+maxDate.substr(0,4),
  onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
    let datepicker = datepickers.find(entry => entry.id == $(this).attr('id'));
    $(`#${datepicker.coid}`).datepicker('option', datepicker.limiter, selectedDate);
    datepicker.value = yymmddUTC(selectedDate);
    myDataTable.draw();
  }
}).on('change', function(){
  datepickers[datepickers.findIndex(item => item.id == $(this).attr('id'))].value = yymmddUTC($(this).val());
  myDataTable.draw();
});
//External search function
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((settings, row) => {
  let rowDate = yymmddUTC(row[3]);
  return (rowDate >= datepickers[0].value || datepickers[0].value == null) && (rowDate <= datepickers[1].value || datepickers[1].value == null);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>Start date:</label>
    <input id="startdate" class="datepicker"></input>
    <label>End date:</label>
    <input id="enddate" class="datepicker"></input>
    <table id="staff"></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to do this if the date is in `yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s` format in the datatable, and i need to search using only `yyyy-mm-dd` while show format in the datatable as  `yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s` ? any suggestion will be of much help. Thanks in advance. @Curr195

Comment: i omitted the yymmddUTC function usage and used @AndroidNoobie's approach of getting time format with `getTime()` in places of your date filtering, as i had my date time as `yy-mm-dd h:i:s` format i faced some difficulties at the beginning, anyway, both @Cur195 and @AndroidNoobie's answers helped to get the job done. thank you very much

Comment: one thing though, in chrome, the input fields for datepicker shows previously selected dates like a drop down list, which is very annoying, any tips to resolve this? also how can i deselect the dates and go back to previous full list after i filtered once ? (sorry if this is annoying, but would post a different question if this was not releated to this answer.)

Answer (score 4):

I made a few modifications to your code. See comments in the JavaScript snippet below, the bulk of which are at the bottom, under your `var myDataTable = $('#staff').DataTable()` declaration:

```js
// I changed some of the start_date values to be more recent, just for testing.
var myTableData = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2017/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Garrett Winters",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$170,750",
    "start_date": "2018/07/25",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "8422"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Ashton Cox",
    "position": "Junior Technical Author",
    "salary": "$86,000",
    "start_date": "2019/01/12",
    "office": "San Francisco",
    "extn": "1562"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2018/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Airi Satou",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$162,700",
    "start_date": "2018/11/28",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "5407"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Brielle Williamson",
    "position": "Integration Specialist",
    "salary": "$372,000",
    "start_date": "2018/12/02",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4804"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "Herrod Chandler",
    "position": "Sales Assistant",
    "salary": "$137,500",
    "start_date": "2018/08/06",
    "office": "San Francisco",
    "extn": "9608"
  }
];

var myDataTable = $('#staff').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: myTableData,
  columns: [{
      title: 'Name',
      data: 'name'
    },
    {
      title: 'Position',
      data: 'position'
    },
    {
      title: 'Office',
      data: 'office'
    },
    {
      title: 'Hire date',
      data: 'start_date'
    },
    {
      title: 'Salary',
      data: 'salary'
    }
  ]
});

// I instantiate the two datepickers here, instead of all at once like before.
// I also changed the dateFormat to match the format of the dates in the data table.
$("#startdate").datepicker({
  "dateFormat": "yy/mm/dd",
  "onSelect": function(date) {  // This handler kicks off the filtering.
    minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
    myDataTable.draw(); // Redraw the table with the filtered data.
  }
}).keyup(function() {
  minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
  myDataTable.draw();
});

$("#enddate").datepicker({
  "dateFormat": "yy/mm/dd",
  "onSelect": function(date) {
    maxDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
    myDataTable.draw();
  }
}).keyup(function() {
  maxDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
  myDataTable.draw();
});

// The below code actually does the date filtering.
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
      aData._date = new Date(aData[3]).getTime(); // Your date column is 3, hence aData[3].
    }

    if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
      if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<label>Start date:</label>
<input id="startdate" class="date_range_filter" />
<label>End date:</label>
<input id="enddate" class="date_range_filter" />
<table id="staff"></table>
```

I also removed the "Filter" button, as it's not needed in this implementation. The table should automatically update when you select a date from the datepickers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this code part to take date range and hire date.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
     function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var min = $('#startdate').datepicker("getDate");
        var max = $('#enddate').datepicker("getDate");
        var hireDate = new Date(data[3]);
        if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
        if (min == null && hireDate <= max) { return true;}
        if(max == null && hireDate >= min) {return true;}
        if (hireDate <= max && hireDate >= min) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
    );
    });
```

and you must click event for your button.

```
$("#filter").click(function () {

    var myDataTable = $('#staff').DataTable();
        myDataTable.draw();
});
```

First code part to get dates , second part to draw datatable again.