# Filter datatable between two datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I just want to filter my datatable when a user selects a date between two datepicker. I have tried a code but it doesn't show when I select a date. Anyone knows how do I fix my code? Thanks so much!

[image: Sample data]

This what I've tried:

```
function implement_cm_table() {
    var table = $('#show-cm-table').DataTable({
        autoWidth: false,
        responsive: true,
        dom: '<"datatable-header"fl><"datatable-scroll"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
        language: {
            search: '<span>Search</span> _INPUT_',
            lengthMenu: '<span>Show:</span> _MENU_',
            paginate: { 'first': 'First', 'last': 'Last', 'next': '→', 'previous': '←' }
        }
    });

    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
            var max = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');
            var startDate = new Date(data[0]);
            if (min == null && max == null) return true;
            if (min == null && startDate <= max) return true;
            if (max == null && startDate >= min) return true;
            if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) return true;
            return false;
        }
    );

    $('#min').datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $('#max').datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min, #max').change(function () {
        table.draw();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you make your code runnable ?

Comment: My code is not working. When I select a date from two datepickers nothing happens.

Comment: Can you help me, please? @Swati

Comment: Yes , but first make your code runnable then it would be easy to solve your problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the solution provided on the DataTables web site [here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/range_dates), or on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717543/how-do-i-filter-date-range-in-datatables), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691908/datatablesdatepicker-filter-table-by-date-range), and in other answers? Do any of these help?

Comment: Also, as swati mentioned, a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or similar, would let us see your data and runnable code. But you can also debug your own code using your browser's console (F11), with `console.log(...);` statements to see how your dates are being handled.

Comment: Can you check my code? I've made it runnable. Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/f6v9axh0

Comment: Help me guys, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the following changes to your code:

1. Wrap your implement function in a document-ready function:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    implement_cm_table();
  } );
</script>
```

2. Change the `min` and `max` selector names to `from` and `to`, here:

```js
    $('#from').datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $('#to').datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#from, #to').change(function () {
        table.draw();
    });
```

3. Now, you have each datepicker declared in 2 different places. So, you need to remove the initial code which is here:

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#from').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    $('#to').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  </script>
```

...and instead add those date formatters to the other `datepicker` declarations, towards the botton of your script:

```js
    $('#from').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $('#to').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
```

After I made these changes to my version of your code, the filtering started working correctly.

Basically, the document ready function is needed to ensure the page is ready for DataTables to be initialized. And then you need to fix the incorrect date picker selectors and make sure each selector is only declared one time.

Comment: You are welcome - I am glad it helped. One small suggestion for the future: There is generally no need to say "please help" in a question, or in comments. The best way to get a quick, helpful answer is to ask a well-written question. Saying "please help" may even be counter-productive. This is a community of volunteers, who try to help as best they can, when they have some spare time.

Comment: Hey there, how can I display the date today in datepicker? Thanks!

Comment: You should really ask this as a new question - but here is one way: `$( "#from" ).datepicker( "setDate", "2020-10-25" );`. The documentation is [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate).